# How to send image from angular 2 for ImageField in restful API?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework, typescript2.0

Recently i am working to upload image from angular 2 and saving it in django. for that purpose, i have made restful django API. that API is working and upload image in folder and saves path of image in attribute .

Now, where i am confuse is, in which format should i send image to django. like i select file from angular 2 and convert it in base64. but it not working. here are my files.

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from time import time


def get_name(instance,filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s"%(str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)

# Create your models here.
class Mobile(models.Model):

    SNR_Name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_Model= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_RAM= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_InternalMemory= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_CompleteName= models.CharField(max_length=200, default="---")
    SNR_ScreenSize= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_ExternalMemory= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_ProcessorSpeed= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SNR_Other= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    SNR_Available=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

    SNR_Link= models.CharField(max_length=1200,default="http.shopnroar.com")


    SNR_Price =models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,default=00)
    SNR_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    SNR_Thumbnail=models.FileField(upload_to=get_name, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('SNR_Name', 'SNR_Model','SNR_RAM','SNR_Link'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.SNR_Name+' , '+self.SNR_Model+' , '+self.SNR_RAM+' , '+self.SNR_ProcessorSpeed+' , '+self.SNR_InternalMemory+' , '+self.SNR_ExternalMemory+','+self.SNR_CompleteName+' , '+self.SNR_ScreenSize+' , '+str(self.SNR_Price)+' , '+self.SNR_Other+','+self.SNR_Available+' , '+self.SNR_Link+' , '+str(self.SNR_Thumbnail)
```

and

**Serilizer.py**

```
    from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Mobile

class Mobile_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Mobile
        fields=('SNR_Name','SNR_Model','SNR_RAM','SNR_ProcessorSpeed' , 'SNR_InternalMemory','SNR_ExternalMemory','SNR_CompleteName','SNR_ScreenSize','SNR_Price','SNR_Other','SNR_Available','SNR_Link','SNR_Thumbnail')
```

and my **view.py**

```
def add_Mobiles(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        serializer = Mobile_Serializer(data=request.data)


        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when i run it throw django admin, it upload images.
but how will it work in my API. i am sending base64 image in SNR_Thumbnail but its giving me error. 
can anyone has solution to this? from angular 2 how can i send image in django or any other hack for it.
i will be very thankful for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Base64ImageField` in your serializer. You have to install [**drf-extra-fields**](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) to use it.
And then, in your `Mobile_Serializer`

```
class Mobile_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     image = Base64ImageField(required=False)
     .....................
```

Comment: than what will happen? base64 image will be stored in folder and ptah will in SNR_thumbnail field?